# Crash when using boost::timed_join and FreeLibrary

Tags: c++, dll, segmentation-fault, boost-thread, freeze

I require the use of `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress` to call functions from some dlls (which plug into my app), but I don't want them to be able to hang my program by containing an infinite loop or hanging themselves, so I'm trying to use `boost::thread` (no experience) to circumvent that. However, if a function does hang, I crash with ACCESS_DENIED (0x00000005) when calling `FreeLibrary` to clean up.

Here's a minimal DLL (`mydll.dll`) that reproduces the problem:

```
extern "C" {
    void __declspec(dllexport) foo() {
        for(;;); //<-- infinite loop
    }
}
```

And here's a minimal cpp that crashes. I've left out error checking for brevity, but I can assure you no errors are given:

```
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

int main() {
    using FuncType = void (*)();

    HMODULE dll = LoadLibrary("mydll.dll");

    FuncType func = (FuncType)GetProcAddress(dll, "foo");

    boost::thread thr = [func] {func();};

    if (!thr.timed_join(boost::posix_time::seconds(1))) {
        std::cout << "Timed out.";
        //thr.detach();
        FreeLibrary(dll);
    }

    for (;;);
}
```

Upon running this, "Timed out." is printed and the call stack (gdb on CodeBlocks) at the crash is as follows:

```
#0 00000000 0x6c1c1214 in ??() (??:??)
#1 0040133E operator() (__closure=<optimized out>) (C:\...\thread test.cpp:17)
#5 00000000 0x00000000 in ??() (??:??)
```

Without optimizations, that becomes:

```
#0 00000000 0x6c1c1214 in ??() (??:??)
#1 00401348 operator() (__closure=0x898f90) (C:\...\thread test.cpp:17)
#2 00401780 boost::detail::thread_data<main()::<lambda()> >::run(void)(this=0x898f70) (c:/.../boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp:62)
#5 00000000 0x00000000 in ??() (??:??)
```

The first thing I tried was adding in the `thr.detach();` line that I commented out above, but that produced the same result.

I've also tried the following to no avail:

- Replacing the lambda with a function (I'm not sure how well Boost fits in with C++11 stuff) --- crashes
- Commenting out the `FreeLibrary` line --- works fine, but I'd rather free it after loading it, even if it is reference-based. I'm also cautious about that kind of behaviour working later on.
- Replacing the infinite loop in the DLL with one that returns --- works fine, but I can't count on that
- Not using `LoadLibrary` or anything and inlining the infinite loop --- works fine, but I need to use DLLs:

> boost::thread thr = []{for (;;);};

The DLL and cpp were both compiled on Windows 7 64-bit using GCC 4.7.1 with 32-bit output types. My version of Boost is 1.49.0. If memory serves, I think I got one or two tests in on Windows XP 32-bit (same compiler etc) before moving to a different computer as well.

Why is this crashing? How can I ensure a function I call dynamically doesn't hang my program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fundamentally, you can't do that. Threads don't provide that kind of isolation. Use processes if you need that.

Comment: This might be getting a bit off topic, but is it possible to create a process with entry being an arbitrary function in a DLL? That's the reason I was just calling it like I am in the first place and decided on a separate thread for the call with a way to stop it if it takes too long. Does the entry point function have that ability, and does it have to be named `DllMain`?

Comment: @chris: You can (and probably should) do it with a wrapper program. The wrapper program can include logic to shut the process down if it takes to long, report its status, take commands from another process, and so on. You can use a single executable by having a way to invoke it as a helper process, such as by a particular command line flag.

Comment: Interesting. I wasn't planning on that, as the one making these calls had the purpose of being able to store a list of plugins and "run" them when it starts, as well as being able to control options for each. It was supposed to be a manager for all of the small programs I use, but are all over the place. I'll try having a helper process to control that logic whenever I communicate with a plugin and see how it goes. Meanwhile, I'll see if anyone else has anything to say here.

Comment: Hold on, is there any reason it works when I remove the `FreeLibrary` line, or is that behaviour unreliable?

Comment: @chris: The library is now forever in use and the process context is contaminated. Yeah, totally unreliable.